# get current element and show data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I want to show current element data when hove on image.

this is my php code.

```
<div class="staff">
    <?php
        $staff_arg = array('post_type'=>'staff','posts_per_page'=>4,'order'=>'DESC');
        $get_staff = new WP_QUERY($staff_arg);

        if($get_staff->have_posts()){
            global $post;
            while($get_staff->have_posts()) : $get_staff->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="content_staff">


                    <?php
                        if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                            the_post_thumbnail();
                        }
                     ?>

                </div>
                <div class="hover_staff" id="temp_" style="display:none">
                    <h3><?php echo $post->post_title;?></h3>
                    <span><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'professional', true)?></span>
                     <p><?php echo $post->post_content;?></p>
                </div>
            <?php
            endwhile;
        }
     ?>
</div>
```

first time  `hover_staff` div is hide and it'll be show after hovering current image.

i do following jquery code for it but it display all

```
jQuery('.content_staff img').on('hover',function(){

    if(jQuery(this)){
        jQuery('.hover_staff').show();
    }
})
```

And HTML LIke

```
<div class="content_staff">
  <img width="225" height="225" sizes="(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 67vw, (max-width: 984px) 60vw, (max-width: 1362px) 62vw, 840px" srcset="http://192.168.1.179/lancemontana/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/s2.jpeg 225w, http://192.168.1.179/lancemontana/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/s2-150x150.jpeg 150w" alt="s2" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" src="http://192.168.1.179/lancemontana/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/s2.jpeg">                    
</div>
```

How could i do this ?

Comment: `jQuery(this)` would be always truthy..... so `if(jQuery(this))` doesn't make any sense

Comment: Please use the `<>` snippet editor to give a [mcve] - what is `if(jQuery(this)){` supposed to do?

Comment: You likely want  `$('.content_staff img').hover(function() { $('.hover_staff').toggle(); });`

Comment: No i want to show hover staff div enable when mouse hover on current image and only show hover staff for current image not to all.

Comment: you're using a class` jQuery('.hover_staff').show();` so all elements with this class will always show. something like jQuery('.hover_staff[data-id=imgId').show();` is needed for your code to know which image to display. you can probably get an attribute from your img element to serve as selector